# css or xpath :select the first 2 elements

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I practice Scrapy and want to ask a question:

the website I want to scrap has a structure like this:

```
<td class="c3">
    <div class="text">
        <a class="title" href="https:// ">movie</a>
        <a  href="https:/ ">movieEN</a>
        <p><ins><a hpp="thisweek-guide" href="https:// ">see more</a></ins></p>
    </div>
</td>
```

But I only want the first 2 href element (movie and MovieEN) without the last one (see more) 
How can I do ?
Here is my code and don't work

`ssel.css("td.c3 a:nth-child(-n+3)::text").extract()`

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 things:

- `a:nth-child(-n+3)` would select the first 3 children of a *parent* element.

In your case it would select all 3 `a` elements: the first 2 are children 1 and 2 of `<div class="text">`, the last one is the 1st child of `<ins>`

- I think `a:nth-child(-n+3)` is not translated correctly by `cssselect` with negative values of *n* in *an+b* forms (scrapy uses cssselect internally)

Check this:

```
>>> cssselect.HTMLTranslator().css_to_xpath('a:nth-child(-n+3)')
u"descendant-or-self::*/*[name() = 'a' and ((position() -3) mod -1 = 0 and position() >= 3)]"
```

It should be something like `u"descendant-or-self::*/*[name() = 'a' and ((position() -3) mod -1 = 0 and position() <= 3)]"`

I suggest you use a combination of CSS selector and XPath (you can chain them in scrapy):

```
In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""
   ...: <td class="c3">
   ...:     <div class="text">
   ...:         <a class="title" href="https:// ">movie</a>
   ...:         <a  href="https:/ ">movieEN</a>
   ...:         <p><ins><a hpp="thisweek-guide" href="https:// ">see more</a></ins></p>
   ...:     </div>
   ...: </td>""")

In [3]: selector.css("td.c3 a:nth-child(-n+3)::text").extract()
Out[3]: []


In [4]: selector.css("td.c3").xpath("(.//a)[position() < last()]//text()").extract()
Out[4]: [u'movie', u'movieEN']

In [5]:
```

Or if you only consider children of `<div class="text">`:

```
In [8]: selector.css("td.c3 > * > a::text").extract()
Out[8]: [u'movie', u'movieEN']

In [9]: selector.css("td.c3 div.text > a::text").extract()
Out[9]: [u'movie', u'movieEN']
```